# Why is : $ K_{ \mathbb{P}^{n} } = -(n+1) H = \mathcal{O}_{ \mathbb{P}^{n} } (-n-1) $?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, line-bundles

Consider the canonical bundle $ K_{ \mathbb{P}^{n} } = \bigwedge^n T_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}^* $, which is the line bundle whose sections are holomorphic forms of top degree, expressible locally as $ f(z_1 , \dots , z_n ) dz_1 \wedge \dots \wedge z_n $. For $ \omega $ an $n$-form on $ \mathbb{P}^n $, write $ ( \omega ) $ for the corresponding divisor.

**Questions** :

Why does the canonical class $ K_{ \mathbb{P}^{n} } $ of $ \mathbb{P}^n $, which is the class equivalence of $ ( \omega ) $ in $ \mathrm{Pic} ( \mathbb{P}^{n} ) = \{ \ \text{line bundles on} \ \mathbb{P}^n \ \} = \{ \ \text{divisors on} \ \mathbb{P}^n \ \} / \sim \ $ checks the following property :
$$ K_{ \mathbb{P}^{n} } = -(n+1) H = \mathcal{O}_{ \mathbb{P}^{n} } (-n-1) $$
such that $ H $ the hyperplane of $ \mathbb{A}^n $ at infinity.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest argument is to use the Euler sequence: $0\to \Omega^1\to O(-1)^{n+1}\to O\to 0$. Taking maximal exteriors you get $\Lambda^n\Omega^1=O(-n-1)$.

Comment: Thank you.  :-) Why is : $ -(n+1) H = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}} (-n-1)$ ?

Comment: @YoYo What is your definition for both sides? One side is a divisor and the other a line bundle.

Comment: For $ -(n+1) H $, it's the divisor of the meromorphic differential $ \omega = dz_1 \wedge \dots \wedge dz_n $ which is holomorphic and non vanishing on $ \mathbb{A}^n $, and on the hyperplane $ H $ at $ \infty $, it has a pole of order $ n+1 $. For the other side $ \mathcal{O}_{ \mathbb{P}^{n} } (-n-1) $, i have no idea about this object.

Comment: @YoYo It is best you read it up. Divisors on smooth varieties are associated to line bundles and in that context, these two are the same.

Comment: But, i don't understand the meaning of $ -n-1 $ inside $ \mathcal{O}_{ \mathbb{P}^{n}} ( -n-1 ) $. Why do we have $ -n-1 $, instead of $ n+4 $ for example ?  :-)

Comment: @YoYo I do not understand your question. $n+4$?

Comment: Ok, Thank you @Mohan, i've just took a look to my course, and it's said that $ \mathcal{O} (H) \simeq \mathcal{O} (1) $ for every hyperplane $ H \subset \mathbb{P}^{n} $. We finally conclude that $ -(n+1) H = \mathcal{O}_{ \mathbb{P}^{n} } ( -n-1 ) $. Thank you Mohan again for your answers above.  :-)